# Browser Back Button same scrollheight where i left before

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling how to code this one.
Is there a way to have the browser back button the same scrollheight i left before proceeding to another page. For example, The scrollheight is 600, I click on the link and redirect to different page then when i hit the back button of the browser the scrollheight is still 600.
I don't have a code yet i don't know how to start. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a single page application? Are you using a specific routing framework/library? What have you tried so far? It definitely is possible

Comment: There's no framework or library i use so far. i search and try this one $(window).on("unload", function() {$.cookie('scrollTop',$(window).scrollTop());}); but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the scrollheight and store it in localstorage then proceed to the next page. Upon pressing back button, you will return to the page so the code must add condition to check if localstorage is set then fetch the previous scroll state from it else show default. Something like this:

```
let scrollPos = localstorage.getItem('scrollPos');
if(scrollPos){
  $('#mydiv')..scrollTop(Number(scrollPos));
}
```

Comment: Hello, How do i check if the value of the scrollPos that inserted in the localstorage?

Comment: $("div.demo").scrollTop( 200 ); will get you the vaue of scrollpos and console.log it to see it

Comment: may scrollbar doesn't shown after the page is fully loaded, how can i use the scrolltop after detecting that the scrollbar is visible.

Comment: Hello, my browser doesn't scrolls immediately after the page load due to the scrollbar is not visible.

Comment: Happy to help :)